# Как проверить наличие данных в таблице SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть форма регистрации и входа. Требуется, чтобы если пользователь регистриурует аккаунт с таким же email, ником или паролем, ему выдавало сообщение об ошибке (тостом) и не регестрировало аккаунт. Как проверить вхождение определенных данных в таблицу? Код вот:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnReg;
    EditText etName, etEmail, etPass1, etPass2;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        Log.d("MyLogs", "Создали рег активити");

        btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
        btnReg.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        etPass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass1);
        etPass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass2);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass1 = etPass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2 = etPass2.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn_reg:
                if (name.equals("") || email.equals("") || pass1.equals("") || pass2.equals("")) {
                    Log.d("MyLogs", "Пустые поля");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Все поля должны быть заполнены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if (!pass1.equals(pass2)) {
                    Log.d("MyLogs", "Несовпадают пароли");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Пароли должны совпадать!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if (!email.contains("@")) {
                    Log.d("MyLogs", "Неверное мыло");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Еmail неверный!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else { Log.d("MyLogs", "Добавляем акк");
                   contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MAIL, email);
                   contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
                   contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PASS, pass1);

                   database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);

                    Log.d("MyLogs", "Уходим в main");
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
        }
        database.close();
    }
}


class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDb";
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_MAIL = "mail";
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "pass";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_MAIL + " text" + KEY_PASS + "text" + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_USERS);

        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл регистрации на локальном устройстве? Если за регистрацию отвечает внешний сервер, он и должен проверять входные данные, и отсылать нужные коды ошибок или сообщения. Проверить есть ли данные в бд можно обычным select запросом!

Comment: Я делаю это задание в качестве тренировки, это не реальный заказ. SQL знаю плохо, вот и спрашиваю как проверить есть ли данные в бд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка существования User'а по его *email*, упрощенный вариант.

Kotlin:

```
fun isUserExist(user: User): Boolean {
    val db = dbHelper.readableDatabase

        val cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM ${TABLE_USERS} WHERE ${KEY_MAIL}='$item.email'"
        ).toSqlQuery(), null)
        cursor.use {
            return it.moveToFirst()
        }
}
```